# Python sees uninstalled module

Tags: python, pyramid

I have a really weird problem. I'm developing a Pyramid project and it seems like **non-existing** module is found when I run `pserve`.

`__init__.py` of my main module:

```
...
# This works !!! db/models directory does not even exists
from db.models import Base
# Also works - db/model exists
from db.model import Base
...
```

I even tried to recreate my virtual environment and it still finds it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you used to have a db/models.py?  If so, you probably have a db/models.pyc lying around.  Remove that.

Comment: What does `import db.models; print(db.models.__file__)` say is being imported?

Comment: @SethMMorton Thanks man. I was thinking the same first but I failed to notice the .pyc file so I was searching for about an hour confused and hungry...

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it appears this was solved and it was leftover `*.pyc` files.  This problem can come up a lot if you're moving between branches or if you find yourself frequently renaming/deleting files.

`$ find mydir -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;` will recursively find all `*.pyc` files in the "mydir" directory (replace mydir with your directory name of course) and delete them.  `$ find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;` for your current working directory.

If you're using git for your project, add this script to your post-checkout hook to prevent differences between branches from getting in your way.

`$ echo "find src -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;" >> .git/hooks/post-checkout`